# ReactiveX: How is Asynchronous Behavior Achieved

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, reactivex

RxJS Observables are functions that can return zero to infinite values, over time, synchronously or asynchronously.

But how exactly is asynchronous behavior achieved? Does it use separate threads somehow, or does it use a Web API and the JS event loop?

Comment: I'd guess it uses JS events - something akin to `window.DispatchEvent` -> `addEventListener`.

Comment: The same way Ajax calls are asynchronous, I guess, or database calls, or file readings (in Nodejs)

Comment: I believe AJAX achieves asynchronous behavior by using various built-in browser APIs (aka. Web APIs), such as XMLHttpRequest. These APIs are built into the browser, and so they are handled in separate threads to the main execution thread. When these functions are ready to execute, the Web API pushes them to the event loop, which in turn pushes the functions onto the call stack as soon as the call stack is empty. I am not sure if RxJS uses built-in browser APIs like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asynchronous behaviour stems from the runtime environment's APIs.

For example, the [implementation of `fromEvent`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/observable/FromEventObservable.ts#L196-L223) calls `addEventListener` and the [implementation of `AjaxObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts#L36-L58) creates an `XMLHttpRequest`.

RxJS can introduce asynchronous behaviour to otherwise synchronous observables using schedulers. For example, observables created using `of` emit synchronously:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .of(1, 2, 3)
  .subscribe(value => console.log("emitted", value));
console.log("subscribed");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

However, if a scheduler is specified, values will be emitted (usually asynchronously) using the scheduler:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .of(1, 2, 3, Rx.Scheduler.asap)
  .subscribe(value => console.log("emitted", value));
console.log("subscribed");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

There are several schedulers in RxJS and they are all implemented using asynchronous browser APIs:

- the `AsyncScheduler` uses [`setInterval`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/scheduler/AsyncAction.ts#L71-L73);
- the `AsapScheduler` uses [`setImmediate`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/scheduler/AsapAction.ts#L17-L30); and
- the `AnimationFrameScheduler` uses [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/scheduler/AnimationFrameAction.ts#L17-L30).

Of course, RxJS can be also used with Node.js and, in that environment, Node's APIs are used.